# How to boot Windows 8 after an Ubuntu specific partition install?

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-8, boot, partitioning

I have an EFI based laptop with Windows 8 pre-installed. I wanted to install Ubuntu 12.04 in dual boot, started from the **Windows** boot manager.

I shrinked a Windows partition, booted Ubuntu from a USB and installed it in the empty space (seen then as `/dev/sda8`)  freed up above. I specifically chose the boot partition to be on the same partition as Ubuntu (`/dev/sda8`).

My expectation was that I would reboot to Windows (since the boot loader was expected not to be touched) and then configure the Windows boot loader to look for Ubuntu.

Since I am typing this from Ubuntu you may have guessed that it did not go that way :)

Upon rebooting I have the Ubuntu boot manager

[image]

but the `Windows Boot Manager` entry unfortunately does not work (the first picture is the left side of the screen, the second one - the right one):

[image]

[image]

I hope that all the partitions are still there (looks so from gparted):

[image]

It looks like from the error that the Linux boot manager does want to load the right partition (`/dev/sda2`).

I can use any of the boot managers, whatever works. How can I either recover the Windows boot manager and then configure it to boot the Linux partition, or have Windows boot from the Linux one?

Comment: Get a windows 8 DVD of your edition and repair your system. After you repair you would only be able to boot into windows. After you log into windows 8 just change the boot menu from there via bcdedit (you can obtain the commands on internet just google it). I assume that boot menu only works from the previously installed OS.

Comment: Thank you for the information. I do not have a Windows 8 DVD, the system came pre-installed. Short of, hmmm, getting it anyway a way or another, is there a way to do the repair without the DVD (a rescue system built upon another Windows install for instance)?

Comment: Nope there isn't, only way to repair is with a windows 8 repair disc or windows 8 disc. There isn't any way that doesn't require a installation disc. Also if you hadn't installed ubuntu over windows there might be a way to get the repair menu. You can try pressing F8 as soon as the computer starts (flash screen) and then get the repair menu.

Comment: See [this question and answer](http://askubuntu.com/questions/335019/unable-to-boot-windows-8-after-ubuntu-installation) on askubuntu.com. Concerning Hunter's declaration that it can't be done, this is an example of [Clarke's first law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clarke%27s_three_laws) (although I make no claims about Hunter's age, profession, or reputation).